# Barcode Scann Google Glasses

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I started to develop with google glasses and working on a barcode scanner. There for I'm searching a scanner who scan's my bardcode and returns the number. The number later on will be used to get informations about the produkt.
I already tryed to use zxing but gives me some problems with the scanner itself. Cant s

I just simply want to scan a code and then use the code later in my programm.

Answer (score 0):

Zxing library worked for me.

Here is a similiar question to yours: [Barcode Scanner doesn't work on Glass GDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615037/barcode-scanner-doesnt-work-on-glass-gdk) .

Have a look also on "BarcodEye" project . https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye . This helped me to solve my issues with barcodescanner.

Hope this helps. Good luck!